# pandas group by and add columns data based on conditions

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have merged test data as below:

```
Device       time    Key score
Computers 2018-01-01 14.0 4.0
Computers 2018-01-01 11.0 4.0
Computers 2018-01-01 16.0 0.0
```

I need to group data by columns [Device,time] and by max value from column score and get minimum key value assigned to this score.

My 1 atempt:

```
df_out = df_out.groupby(['Device', 'time'])['score'].max().reset_index()
```

Output 1:

```
Device       time    score
Computers 2018-01-01 4.0
```

My 2 atempt:

```
df_out = df_out.groupby(['Device', 'time'])['score', 'Key'].max().reset_index()
```

Output 2:

```
Device       time    score Key
Computers 2018-01-01 4.0  14.0
```

How to get assigned proper minimum Key?

Desired output:

```
Device       time    score Key
Computers 2018-01-01 4.0  11.0
```

Thanks for You hard work.

Comment: You can inner join the resulting dataframe with the original one, on Device, time and score.

Comment: try using nlargest

Comment: So you want the maximum score and, if maximum score is not unique, the one with minimum key?

Comment: @Valentino yes that is what i want

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `transform`:

```
df[df.score.eq(df.groupby(['Device', 'time'])['score'].transform('max'))]
```

---

```
      Device        time   Key  score
0  Computers  2018-01-01  14.0    4.0
```

As per EDIT:

```
df.groupby(['Device', 'time'],as_index=False).agg({'score':'max','Key':'min'})
```

---

```
      Device        time  score   Key
0  Computers  2018-01-01    4.0  11.0
```

Comment: sorry i updated my question with another parameter [min key value]

Answer (score 2):

Using `apply` and custom function to get the desired row with `loc`:

```
def selecting(x):
    subx = x.loc[x['score'] == x['score'].max()]
    return subx.loc[subx['Key'].idxmin()]

ddf = df.groupby(['Device', 'time']).apply(selecting)
```

Using your sample input, this will give:

```
1                        Device        time   Key  score
Device    time                                          
Computers 2018-01-01  Computers  2018-01-01  11.0    4.0
```

You can drop the multi-index using `.reset_index(drop=True)` on the result.

I edited the answer using a custom function, to perform correctly the selection. I realized that the previous version of my answer may raise a `KeyError` on more complex dataframes.